# Php Apache2 Insert Large Binary MSSQL error: Changed database context to 'database'

Tags: php, sql-server, insert, binary, apache2

I've been pouring over the web and can't seem to find a solution to my problem.

I have a simple form for uploading vector graphics (ai, eps, pdf, svg) that converts them with imagemagik into jpgs and stores both files in MSSql 2000 in "image" fields.

We receive the error "MSSQL error: Changed database context to 'out-database' for anything uploaded over 16 megs.

I know its not the preferred way to store these files... but it has worked flawlessly for us until we started receiving large files.  Its also handy for how we handle versions and security.

I'm tailing the apache and php log files and can't find a single error being logged when this happens!?

The webserver and mssql server are beefy machines with boatloads of ram and are located on the same gigabit switch so I'm not worried about performance.  I just need it to work.

Again, this works flawlessly for anything under 16megs which I can find no reference to anywhere.

```
**Our Web Server Specs**
2.6.38-11-server #50-Ubuntu
PHP Version 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.7
Apache Version  Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu)
Apache API Version  20051115
Max Requests    Per Child: 0 - Keep Alive: on - Max Per Connection: 100
Timeouts    Connection: 300 - Keep-Alive: 15

**Php mssql settings**
MSSQL Support   enabled
Active Persistent Links 0
Active Links    0
Library version FreeTDS
Directive   Local Value
mssql.allow_persistent  On
mssql.batchsize 0
mssql.charset   no value
mssql.compatability_mode    Off
mssql.connect_timeout   90
mssql.datetimeconvert   On
mssql.max_links Unlimited
mssql.max_persistent    Unlimited
mssql.max_procs Unlimited
mssql.min_error_severity    11
mssql.min_message_severity  11
mssql.secure_connection Off
mssql.textlimit 2147483647
mssql.textsize  2147483647
mssql.timeout   180

**Other relevant php.ini settings**
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 300
memory_limit = 512M
post_max_size = 300M
upload_file_size = 300M
default_socket_timeout = 60
odbc.defaultlrl = 2147483647
odbc.defaultbinmode = 1
```

Relevant code snippet:

```
        $f1 = ("" .$outloc . $clean1 . "");
        $f1string  =  file_get_contents($f1); 
        $f1data  =  unpack("H*hex", $f1string);
        $cf1 = ("" .$outloc . $confilename1 . $outext . "");
        $cf1string  =  file_get_contents($cf1); 
        $cf1data  =  unpack("H*hex", $cf1string);
        $cf1name = ("" .$confilename1 . $outext. "");

        //Upload to database
        $query_result  =  mssql_query("INSERT INTO art_converted_table (image_blob,filename,comment,received_dt,image_name,contact_email,po_number,upload_blob,upload_mime,upload_filename) VALUES (0x".$cf1data['hex'].",'$cf1name','$ccomment','$received_dt','$clean1','$email','$cponum',0x".$f1data['hex'].",'$file1type','$clean1')", $db_conn)
        or die('MSSQL error: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
```

I've tried manually adding sleep() timers after the unpack process incase that could be the issue.  I'm just befuddle as to why this is happening.

Is there a max length to the hex string that can be inserted to mssql?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Just to make sure this wasn't an issue with the SQL server itself, I created a ASP page on our IIS server and was able to upload 100+ meg files no problem.  This is def an issue with php... ARGH!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with large files and PHP and got around it by using the PHP FTP extension as described here

"http://au.php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php"

I then ran the my query using mysql.exe and shell_exec(), you could also run the query from your web application.

If you are determined to keep using the form then check the size of you post_max_size variable in php.ini the form post may be the bottleneck.